# NSMutableDictionary returns 0xffffffff instead of nil when a key doesn't exist

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, null

I have an NSMutableDictionary that is doing something strange:

```
(gdb) po listenerRegistry
{
}
(gdb) po productID
com.mycompany.productid
(gdb) po [listenerRegistry objectForKey:[productID stringValue]]
0xffffffff does not appear to point to a valid object.
(gdb) po [listenerRegistry class]
__NSCFDictionary
(gdb)
```

According to the docs, `nil` is supposed to be returned for keys that aren't in the dictionary.

Has anyone else seen this before?

Comment: Never seen it before, but incidentally it looks a lot like NSNotFound.

Comment: Wow, you're right.  I think I figured out the problem.

Comment: I ran into this too. I guess I will be doing if(request != nil && request != NSNotFound). Does anybody have any ideas on why? Only seems to happing in this one instance of my various NSDictionary usages. And it doesn't look like we are the only ones. [link](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2010/Oct/msg00026.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The objects inside the `NSMutableDictionary` are of the type `id <MyObserverProtocol>`, and it would appear that Monolo was right in his observation that the returned value looks like `NSNotFound`.

Apparently, Foundation classes return `NSNotFound` when asked for items of that type when they don't exist or aren't found (as discussed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html)).  While the documentation lists `NSArray`s explicitly, I feel compelled to believe the same is happening in my case.